# Mysql remote command using socket file but no password

Tags: mysql, scripting, mariadb

I generally connect to to mariadb using this command

```
sudo -u root  <mysql_env> mysql -S /var/mysql/state/mysql.sock
```

Now I am trying to do remote command to connect another host but its expecting a password which I dont provide at all.Can someone help?

```
sudo <<mysql_env>> mysql -u root -p -S /var/mysql/state/mysql.sock -h remote_hostname -P8989  dbname -e "select * from t1"
```

Error received:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'remote_host_ip' (using password: **YES**)
```

if i don't use -p in the string above its giving me a straight error without asking password:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'remote_host_ip' (using password: **NO**)
```

Comment: remove the -u root and try , also check the location of the .sock file is correct

Comment: I tried & it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

A Unix domain socket or IPC socket (inter-process communication socket) is a data communications endpoint for exchanging data between processes executing on the **same** host operating system.
Connecting to a remote endpoint via unix domain socket is not possible therefore. Instead use TPC by specifying hostname without a socket.